# Typecasting, ints and chars in c++

Tags: c++, types

I'm trying to write a function to detect separators as defined by an assignment and I know it is not good programming style to

```
#define EXCLAMATION_POINT 33, but to instead do #define EXCLAMATION_POINT '!'
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;
#define PERIOD '.'
#define QUESTION_MARK '?'
#define EXCLAMATION_POINT '!'
#define COMMA ','
#define COLON ':'
#define SEMICOLON ';'

inline bool IsSeparator(int x) 
{
    if (isspace(x) || 
        x == PERIOD || 
        x == QUESTION_MARK ||
        x == EXCLAMATION_POINT ||
        x == COMMA ||
        x == COLON || 
        x == SEMICOLON) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    int input;
    cout << "Enter characters: \n";
    input = cin.get();
    if (!IsSeparator(input))
        cout << "true";
    else {
        cout << "false";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But in my IsSeparator(), how do I typecast that int to a char to be compared to '!'.  I thought if I did something like (char)EXCLAMATION_POINT that would work, but it does not and the value is left at an int.  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks!

Comment: Uh, not sure I fully grasp what you're saying about `#define`'s and style, but the *best* method is not to do that at all. Just replace `PERIOD` with `'.'`, and so on. If you really want constants, at least make them `static const char Period = '.'`, no need to use `#define`'s at all, let alone scream. :]

Comment: Also, your code works as expected for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any cast, but:

```
if (!IsSeparator(input))
```

should be:

```
if (IsSeparator(input))
```

Also, your prompt:

```
cout << "Enter characters: \n";
```

implies you can enter multiple characters. So you can, but cin.get() will only read one.

Regarding giving symbolic names to things. Suppose you are parsing a file where the separator is a colon. It then makes sense to say:

```
const char SEPARATOR = ':';
```

because you can then change it when the file format changes, for example to:

```
const char SEPARATOR = '|';
```

but it doesn't normally make sense to give your own names to the members of the ASCII (or whatever) character set.

In your code, it might make sense to create an array of separators (I'm not showing all the ones you use for my ease of typing):

```
const char SEPARATORS[] = {':', '|', '!', 0 };
```

and then have your validation function iterate over the array. Note in this case, the array could also have been expressed as a string literal:

```
const char * const SEPARATORS = ":|!";
```

Answer (score 2):

What gives you the idea that those `#define`s are a good practice *at all*? Are you required to handle the great Exclamation Mark Redefinition of 2015?

It is probably safe to assume that an exclamation mark is going to be represented by `'!'` now and forever. Just like the constant one is going to be represented by  `1` tomorrow as well.

You don't need to define EXCLAMATION_MARK any more than you need to define ONE or MINUS or INT.

Comment: @Kornel: As far as I know, Unicode matches the first 255 characters with ASCII. So `'!'` stays `'!'`. But I know next to nothing about Unicode.

Comment: Well, there are two possibilities: Either the single character `'!'` is an exclamation mark, in which case testing against `'!'` works, or an exclamation mark is represented by some sequence of multiple characters -- but if that is the case, a `#define` doesn't help either, since *no* comparison between individual `char`s is going to work. In that case, you'd have to compare against a sequence of `char`s. So you'd need something like an `is_exclamation_mark()` function instead of comparing a char against a  `#define`